# Magento 1.9 - Wishlist Does Not Work

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

I added items from Wishlist to my cart.
[image]

After you go to the cart page, you will be notified that the item has been added.
[image]

But the cart is empty.
[image]

Please tell me the solution.